# Activate Lightbox by clicking on LI rather than thumbnail

Tags: jquery, lightbox

Using Lightbox for a photo gallery and would like to initiate the function by clicking on the thumbnail's parent `<li>`rather than the thumbnail image. I have been able to do this easily with the thumbnail for the album (not using Lightbox, simply opening another page) with the following code:

```
$(".item").click(function(){
        window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");return false;
    });
```

However, can't seem to initiate Lightbox in a similar fashion. Ideas?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
I am using jQuery Lightbox (0.5), http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Here is the code to initiate:

```
   $('a.lightbox').lightBox();
```

And the HTML (with PHP for details):

```
<a href="http://somewhere.com/gallery/photos/<?php echo $images['filename'];?>.jpg" class="lightbox" title="<?php echo $images['caption'];?>">
```

Comment: Which lightbox library are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could catch the click of the `<li>` and then invoke the click event of the first `<img>` inside that `<li>` with the following code. But this is very hacky, and I do not recommend it. It would help to know which lightbox you're using (there are many), and see some HTML.

```
$(".item").click(function() {
  $(this).find(".lightbox:first").click();
});
```

Comment: Yes, Firebug displays the following: i < length && callback.call( valu...) !== false; value = object[++i] ) {} 
After a few seconds, the image opens in another browser window.. Lightbox does not initiate

Comment: Correction! This is the correct solution, accidentally erased the Lightbox function from my code. Many thanks! :)